# Is 'whom' incorrect in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, whom

As the story unfolds, a malicious rumor about Mr. Simon spreads after the principal suspends a school bully for beating up a female classmate whom he thinks has "cooties."

Comment: Who has ... or Whom has....? That clarifies the doubt.

Comment: I don't like the sound of "cooties"! The pronoun is not object of "thinks" but subject of the embedded "has cooties" clause Since subject pronouns are normally nominative, "who" would be the better choice.

Comment: 'Who' is better, but in informal speech you could eliminate it with no penalty: *a classmate he thinks has 'cooties'* works as well. In either case the antecedent isn't clear from this one snip - is it the principal or the bully who suspects cooties?